# STM32F4 Discovery + Mac OS X + GCC + OpenOCD + Eclipse

Tags: arm, stm32, ide, openocd, cortex-m

I'm interested in buying an STM32F4 Discovery from ST Microelectronics. I'm using Mac OS X, 10.8 and would like to use a toolchain including

- GCC
- OpenOCD for debugging
- Eclipse IDE / IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

and this must work on my Mac.

Would this setup be possible at all?

Comment: I've done gcc and OpenOCD part - it's definately possible. Regarding to eclipse - i've not done that yet, but it should be no problem.

Comment: I've been able to use https://github.com/texane/stlink on Linux and OSX after brief compile fixing to flash the stm32 Cortex M3 parts using the dirt cheap stlink/V2 boards as programmers, and GDB works.  Haven't personally tried it with a Cortex M4 part but expect someone has that working.  Watch out for prebuilt arm versions of gcc with broken compiler libraries though - wasted a day on one of those recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  I haven't tried it yet but I did come across a post I found on hackaday that you might find useful.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/18/stm32f4-discovery-toolchain-mac-os-x/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tutorial for setting up the STM32F3DISCOVERY on Mac OS X (tested on 10.8 and 10.9) using the GNU ARM toolchain, Eclipse and OpenOCD: http://www.davidrojas.co.uk/stm32f3discovery-on-mac-os-x-using-eclipse-gcc-arm-and-openocd/

It should work with the STM32F4DISCOVERY too (they are both Cortex-M4, and use the same debugger), just change the line
source [find target/stm32f3x_stlink.cfg]
in the OpenCD script part for
source [find target/stm32f4x_stlink.cfg]
And when creating a new project, select the STM32F4xx option instead of STM32F3xx.